# swagger-play2 is not able to find its ApiHelpController package path within subproject

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, subproject

I am trying to add swagger to one of my sub-projects. I have added the "ApiHelpController" as below

subproject routes file

```
GET   /swagger.json            controllers.ApiHelpController.getResources
```

subproject conf file

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule"
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
Type ApiHelpController is not a member of package <subproject>.controllers
```

Looks like swagger is not able to find its Controller path within subproject.
How can I fix the the package path for ApiHelpController??

```
playVersion = "2.5.14"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
"io.swagger"  %% "swagger-play2" % "1.5.3",
"org.webjars" % "swagger-ui"     % "2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue on my side. It was more related to play path settings. The issue was due to "controllers" path conflict. Play was trying to find "ApiHelpController" in existing package "controllers" of sub-project. I renamed the package name of sub-project and that solved that problem.

May be there is a better fix, but this works for me.

Comment: What did you rename exactly?